# JS/TS cleverest way how to iterate thru object array and do some changes

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

is there a cleverest way how to achieve the same result?

brief desc:

```
 routes = [
{ name: 'vehicle', activated: true},
{ name: 'userassignment', activated: true},
{ name: 'relations', activated: true},
{ name: 'journeys', activated: true},
{ name: 'expenses', activated: true}
```

];

TASK - create a function which takes above array and:

1. change ALL members property "activated" to false
2. set one specific "chosen" member to true (based on its 'name')
3. if "chosen" is 'journeys' or 'expenses' set them to true BUT ALSO set 'relations' 
   member to true

I did it like the following code but my senior wants it smarter.

```
highlightActiveRoute(array: any[], chosen: string) {
array.forEach(element => {
  element.activated = false;
  if (element.name === chosen) {
    element.activated = true;
    if (element.name === 'journeys' || element.name === 'expenses') {
      this.routes[2].activated = true;
    }
  } 
});
```

}
}

I am not sure if I can write it smarter but maybe you can :) Thank you very much for any inspiration.

Comment: if your code is working but you just want to make it "better" (a subjective term, if ever there was one), then this isn't really the place for it. We fix problems here or sometimes answer technical questions about how to solve something.  You could consider whether your question is more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is “smarter”? In terms of performance or readability?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using only ArrayIterators (ECMAScript 2015). With the following code, you don´t have to worry if any element in the array changes it position:

```
highlightActiveRoute(array: any[], chosen: string) {
array.forEach(element=>{element.activated=false});
if(['journeys','expenses'].includes(chosen))
{  
    array[array.findIndex(element=>{return element.name==='relations'})].activated = true;
    array[array.findIndex(element=>{return element.name==='expenses'})].activated = true;
    array[array.findIndex(element=>{return element.name==='journeys'})].activated = true;
}
else
{
    array[array.findIndex(element=>{return element.name===chosen})].activated = true;
}

return array;
}
```

Comment: Hello Jorge, thank you for your answer... it is maybe not exactly what i am looking for, but the way how to be sure about position in array is very cool, thank you, i will use it :)

Answer (score 0):

I made some minor improvements.. 
First of all, the variable `element.activated` is only overwritten once, istead of two times in your current code. Also decresed the depth of your code, to make it more readable. I hope his helps you. Goodluck!

```
highlightActiveRoute(array: any[], chosen: string) {
    array.forEach(element => {
        element.activated = element.name === chosen; 
        if (element.activated 
            && (element.name === 'journeys' || element.name === 'expenses') ) {
                this.routes[2].activated = true;
        } 
    });
}
```